# Deleting particular value from array

Tags: javascript

```
if (sorted[i].Document === 'abc' || sorted[i].Document === 'xyz') {
    delete sorted[i].Document;
}
```

When i try to remove the particular two documents, it gets removed but the next time it throws me an error saying Document is undefined.

```
var sorted = DocumentListData.Documents.sort(function (a, b) {
    var nameA = a.Document.toLowerCase(),
        nameB = b.Document.toLowerCase();

    return nameA.localeCompare(nameB);
});
```

I am sorting the documents, then iterating it and then trying to remove the documents which are `abc and xyz`.

Comment: It does delete the attribute `Document`, but not the element in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call `toLowerCase` on properties that don't exist because you just deleted them. Check if they exist before attempting to execute methods on them.

```
// i used empty string as the default, you can use whatever you want
var nameA = a.Document ? a.Document.toLowerCase() : '';
var nameB = b.Document ? b.Document.toLowerCase() : '';
```

If you are trying to remove the array elements instead of just their `Document` properties, you should be using `splice` instead of `delete`:

```
if (sorted[i].Document === 'abc' || sorted[i].Document === 'xyz') {
    sorted.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to remove document properties value.